# Append <element>, [attribute], and "property" of elements to itself?

Tags: javascript, loops, attributes, append, polymer

### My Objective:

I'm using [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/) to create custom elements, attributes, and properties for a Flexbox Grid System.

[[FX-Properties]](https://github.com/oneezy/fx-properties)

In an effort to help me debug my process visually, I need some javascript.

I want to append the text of all `<elements>`, `[attributes]` and `"properties"` inside the `<body>` to themselves with **Javascript** (only).

Currently, I'm doing this with `css`'s  `::before` and `::after` Pseudo Elements, but as you can imagine,,, this can be pretty time consuming!

What I've got so far: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oneeezy/dxka2ezz/)

---

**EXAMPLE:**

If I had this:

```
    <div id="div" class="ninja"></div>
```

I want to do this:

```
    <div id="div" class="ninja">
        <div id="div" class="ninja">
    </div>
```

My guess is that the `.attributes` is what I need to work with, but I'm unsure on how to use properly.

```
    <script>
      var body       =  document.querySelector('body').attributes;
      var main       =  document.querySelector('main').attributes;
      var section    =  document.querySelector('section').attributes;
      var div        =  document.querySelector('div').attributes;
    </script>
```

Comment: That's invalid markup, why would you want to do it?

Comment: I'm using Polymer to create `<custom-elements attribute="property">`'s for a flexbox grid system I'm working on. I'm trying to learn how to use Flexbox in the process. This will help me quickly see what's going on visually without having to look under the hood. https://github.com/oneezy/fx-properties

Comment: You'd be better off just opening dev tools and using those. Otherwise, it sounds like you just want to escape the element and add it to itself, which is essentially `node.textContent = node.outerHTML`.

Comment: That's how I've been doing it. The main reason I'm creating this is to get my brain's "muscle memory" working for how Flexbox works. Seeing it visually on screen will just speed up my process. I'm finding it pretty difficult to learn still.

Comment: Then go mess around with [flexbox froggy](http://flexboxfroggy.com/), or [read MDN's article on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). Asking for help with an unrealistic issue for code that you're only using for educational purposes isn't going to help *anyone* in the future.

Comment: This is a realistic issue and I'll soon be teaching my team of *nobodies* on how to use it for the progressive web app we're building. And if you're unable to understand the benefit of why I'm doing this or what web components are I suggest you [read the W3C Web Components Status](https://www.w3.org/standards/techs/components#w3c_all).

Comment: Polymer and flexbox are only incidentally related to the question your asking. **The question itself** is what I'm criticizing, not flexbox or polymer. I will attempt to be more clear this time: trying to add a DOM node's own markup to itself is not a realistic problem that anyone would run into except for your concocted scenario that you yourself admitted to only doing for purposes of testing.

Comment: Yes. That is the reason of why I'm doing this - strictly for teaching/ testing/ debugging purposes...Coincidentally, the same reason StackOverflow was created. It seems to me you've made the assumption that my question doesn't have purpose because it won't be shown to *real users*, and that somehow makes it unimportant? This is where I disagree with you. The *users* of this will be developers. SO is a place for **Teaching, Learning, and Understanding...** There are no stupid questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("*"),
  function(el){ 
    el.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(el.cloneNode(false).outerHTML));
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/odbbybcy/

Comment: I'm a little confused on this... Doesn't seem to be working. https://jsfiddle.net/oneeezy/dxka2ezz/3/